# error C2451: a conditional expression of type 'main::<lambda_1>' is not valid

Tags: c++, lambda

I'm new to programming and I'm trying to review this C++ primer book, however while checking LAMBDA part I get into a compile error on my Visual studio 2022.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i = 10;
    if ([&]()->bool { while(i) --i; return true; })
        cout << "the captured variable is 0" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Appreciate your enlightenment...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lambda returns a `bool` value when called.  But the code is not calling the lambda at all.  It is instead trying to evaluate the lambda object itself in a boolean context, which is not a valid operation since a lambda's generated type does not define a conversion of a lambda object to a `bool`.

You need to actually call the lambda first (ie, invoke the lambda type's function call operator) by placing `()` after the lambda object, and then evaluate its return value afterwards, eg:

```
int main()
{
    int i = 10;
    if ([&]()->bool { while(i) --i; return true; }())
                                               // ^ add this !
        cout << "the captured variable is 0" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Coding a lambda inside an `if` statement is not a good idea, though.  It is legal, but it makes the code harder to read and understand.  It would be better to assign the lambda to a variable first, and then call it afterwards, eg:

```
int main()
{
    int i = 10;
    auto lambda = [&]() -> bool { while(i) --i; return true; };
    if (lambda())
        cout << "the captured variable is 0" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ([&]()->bool { while(i) --i; return true; })
```

The lambda is not called there. Try

```
if ([&]()->bool { while(i) --i; return true; }())
```

It might be a misprint in the book. I can't find it on [C++ Primer Errata](https://ptgmedia.pearsoncmg.com/images/9780321714114/errata/9780321714114_errata_10-31-12.html).